# xfce4-gtk3 does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, xubuntu, ppa, xfce

I have problem with `xfce4-gtk3` because when updating I get error

```
The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/xubuntu-dev/xfce4-gtk3/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Here is complete output of `apt update`

```
$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily InRelease
Hit:3 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily Release                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                             
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                                                     
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                       
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]                                                                                                                                                                      
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                                                                 
Hit:11 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x xenial InRelease                                                                                                                                 
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                    
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                                                          
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/peek-developers/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                                               
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                                            
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]                                                                                                                                   
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                                                       
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xubuntu-dev/xfce4-gtk3/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                         
Err:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xubuntu-dev/xfce4-gtk3/ubuntu xenial Release                                                                                                           
  403  Forbidden
Ign:20 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                              
Hit:21 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                        
Hit:22 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg InRelease                                                               
Hit:23 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                           
Hit:2 http://screenshots.getdeb.net xenial-getdeb InRelease               
Hit:4 http://screenshots.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb InRelease
Hit:25 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Reading package lists... Done 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/xubuntu-dev/xfce4-gtk3/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Is the problem on my side or coming from xubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking at [Xfce4 port to Gtk3 and gdbus](https://wiki.xubuntu.org/devel/gtk3), both staging PPA and testing PPA seems to be no longer available. The links to PPA on Launchpad.net will only return "Error: Page not found".

> Xfce4 port to Gtk3 and gdbus
>
> Staging PPA: [ppa:unit193/xfce4-gtk3](https://launchpad.net/~unit193/+archive/ubuntu/xfce4-gtk3/+packages)
>
> Testing PPA: [ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce4-gtk3](https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/ubuntu/xfce4-gtk3/+packages)

The error you are seeing is likely due to the testing PPA being deprecated by Xubuntu Development team. In Xubuntu, go to **Settings** > **Software & Updates** > **Other Software** to remove the testing PPA and run update again to see without errors.